# How to get an thumbnail that doesn't exceed a certain size in Glide?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I'm getting thumbnail as Bitmap:

```
bitmap = Glide
        .with(context)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(model)
        .submit(width, height)
        .get();
```

And if I give for example width = 300, height = 300 I can get thumbnail whose width = 300, height = 400. this is because of the aspect ratio of the image.

How I can get a reduced thumbnail that will decrease because of the scale, rather than increase? So that the image does not exceed 300 * 300

Comment: have you try .fit().fitCenter ?

Comment: I think this can not be caused after asBitmap()

Comment: In my opinion, I suggest you to create your own Glide's transformation like this ----> https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2391

Comment: Thanks! I'll look it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research for you, found that Glide doesn't provide centerInside() due to memory issue

and I suggest you to take a look at bitmap transformation via Glide's target

[here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2391)